# BODMAS assignment

Tags: java, expression, evaluation

Im working on a problem that goes like this -

Implement a function that evaluates an expression consisting of
following operands : '(', ')', '+', '-', '*', '/'. Each numbers in the
expression could be large (as large as being represented by string of
1000 digits). The '/' (i.e. divide) operand returns the integer
quotient.

The test cases go like -

( ( ( 10000000000000000000000001231234448563465435434723854278423 /
1111111111234623874627 ) * 2342384523 + 123124 - 34534534 ) * (
1231263123242346 + 223423234346 * 234236536 ) )

and could be even longer.

I do not want to use external libraries which are expression evaluators/parsers like JEP and the like.

I was thinking along the lines of BigInteger and then came to know that BigIntegers do not evaluate epressions like Integers do. I also know that parsing is an option where in i would have to simulate the BODMAS behaviour.I would like to know if there is any other way to go about this and if there isnt, would like some pointers on how i could get this implemented.

I am not looking for a readymade solution, just looking for directions to arrive at the solution by myself.

Comment: Whats the problem with BigInteger? The doc says: BigInteger provides analogues to all of Java's primitive integer operators, and all relevant methods from java.lang

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) to evaluate the expression and use [StringTokenizer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) as a spimple lexer to split up the line. You can use `delim = "()/*-+"` and `returnDelims = true`. This will return the numbers and the delimeters whoch in your case are the operators and parenthesis you need to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this as a [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) then implement it using the [state pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). I can't find any examples of a BODMAS state machine unfortunately but they must be out there somewhere.